# Bitrix: Странное поведение умного фильтра

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Наблюдаю проблему в работе умного фильтра. 
пример 1:

- Установили 1 и 2 фильтр, применяем
- Убрали 1 фильтр
- Вернулись назад, видим что стоит 1 и 2 фильтр
- Снимаем 2 фильтр, фильтры пропадают все

пример 2:

- Устанавливаем 1 фильтр, применяем
- Устанавливаем 2 фильтр, применяем
- Возвращаемся назад
- Стоит 1 фильтр и галочка на 2 фильтре(но он не активен в данный момент, т.е просто отмечен
- Обновляем страницу, галочка снимается
  или
- Применяем 3 фильтр, теперь у нас активно 3 фильтра, а не 2

В виртуальной лаборатории точно так-же ... есть варианты фикса ?

Answer (score 0):

Есть варианты фикса :) Если, конечно, я правильно понял из вашего описания ситуацию.
Это понимание того, что вы делаете. Итак:
 1. Установили 1 и 2 фильтр применили. ок.
 2. Убрали 1 фильтр. ок. (ajax запрос отправился на сервер)
 3. Вернулись назад (кнопка назад в браузере?)  страница подтянулась из кеша браузера без запроса к серверу. Естественно галочки там стоят
 4. Снимаем второй фильтр, отправляется аякс запрос. Сервер видит что теперь и вторая галка снята...

Т.е. действие в браузере "Назад" не означает, что применен фильтр который был до этого.

Comment: Да, тут мне понятно что браузер просто показал страницу в том виде в котором она была, вот мне и интересно, как это пофиксить ...

а вот второй пример с галочкой мне не ясен, почему она активна.

Comment: Потому что "галочка" это всего лишь html тег с определенным состоянием. Таково было состояние страницы вот и все дела